# MP3 Tag editing with an encrypted home directory

Tags: encryption, home-directory, mp3, editor, tag

Why can MP3 tag editors not access my encrypted home directory?

I've tried EasyTAG, puddletag, and MP3 Diags...

It seems to be a permission issue, but Banshee can play/edit my music files no problem.

[image]

[image]

`ls -ld / /home $HOME`

```
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Aug 22 12:23 /
drwxr-x--x   4 root root  4096 Sep 12  2012 /home
drwxr-x--x 102 matt matt 36864 Sep  1 11:47 /home/matt
```

And

```
script some.log
easytag
exit
```

Shows:

```
Script started on Mon 02 Sep 2013 16:14:58 EDT
]0;matt@Latitude: ~matt@Latitude:~$ easytag
]0;matt@Latitude: ~matt@Latitude:~$ exit
exit

Script done on Mon 02 Sep 2013 16:15:33 EDT
```

Comment: Can you show us EasyTag, puddletag or MP3 Diags failing? Try "script some.log" followed by the EasyTag, puddletag or MP3 Diags commands failing, then "exit" and examine "some.log", and post parts of it. I'm not sure why you think these unknown (to us) failures are related to your encrypted home directory. It doesn't look encrypted when you're logged in.

Comment: I've added some screen shots, but I couldn't get the log to capture any events: 'script some.log easytag' didn't open EasyTAG

Comment: Mattarn, try launching easytag from the terminal. First make sure that easytag is closed. Then, go to the terminal, and type in easytag.

Comment: Doesn't work, but 'sudo easytag' let's me open my home directory without errors...

Comment: Sounds like an ownership problem try "ls -ld / /home $HOME". root should own the first two, you should own the third. Did you have "script some.log" and "easytag" on two separate lines? And "exit" on a third?

Comment: Yes, I own the third:
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Aug 22 12:23 /
drwxr-x--x   4 root root  4096 Sep 12  2012 /home
drwxr-x--x 102 matt matt 36864 Sep  1 11:47 /home/matt

And script output is:
Script started on Mon 02 Sep 2013 16:14:58 EDT
]0;matt@Latitude: ~matt@Latitude:~$ easytag
]0;matt@Latitude: ~matt@Latitude:~$ exit
exit

Script done on Mon 02 Sep 2013 16:15:33 EDT

Comment: Added outputs to original question as above comment is not formatted...

Comment: I'd do something like (wrapped in `script someother.log<newline>...;exit)", this command "sudo strace -e trace=file easytag" and look at all the files the UID==0 easytag successfully opens. Then, do it without the "sudo". Compare and find where the UID==matt easytag fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a permissions problem to me. On my system,

`walt@squid:~(0)$ ls -ld / /home /home/walt

drwxr-xr-x 27 root root  4096 Dec 11 15:13 /

drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Feb 16  2013 /home

drwx------ 86 walt walt 24576 Dec 11 16:52 /home/walt`

while yours is:

```
ls -ld / /home $HOME

drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Aug 22 12:23 /
drwxr-x--x   4 root root  4096 Sep 12  2012 /home
drwxr-x--x 102 matt matt 36864 Sep  1 11:47 /home/matt
```

I would fix this by  `sudo chmod o+r /home`

I'd like to point out that your "encrypted home directory" looks encrypted only when you're logged off. When you log in, it's overlaid (through `mount` magic) with the decrypted version. "Encrypted home directory" would be part of this problem if you want some other user to process your files while you were logged off.